# CodeIgniter Search Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I’m working on some script and I would like to create search. My project is based on CodeIgniter and my desire is to have all code content compatibile with it. I've already written question like that, but I didn't get enough help and nobody wants to help me, so I opened this question.

I have already working on the query for searching but it’s not good because it doesn’t support more words than one. So if I enter word “test” in my search form (assume that the test word is in database in one of fields) there will be few results, but if I enter words “test test test” (again assume that the test words are in database in one of fields) there will be no any result.

My previous query:

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date, hyperlink')->or_like(array('title' => $query, 'content' => $query))->order_by('id_article', 'desc')->get('news');
```

And after some tweaks:

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date, hyperlink');
foreach ($parts as $q)
{
    $this->db->or_like(array('title' => $q, 'content' => $q));
}
$this->order_by('id_article', 'desc')
$show_results = $this->db->get('news');
```

What's the best way to create good query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code. This will help you more in your search query. It will search for any number of words wherever that word(s) exist.

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date, hyperlink');
$this->db->where("title LIKE '%$query%' OR content LIKE '%$query%'");
```

Hope this helps you.